# Android: Animated gif image resize in kmagick

Tags: android, kotlin, imagemagick, wand

I am using [kmagick](https://github.com/cherryleafroad/kmagick) for resizing gif images in android. It works fine for static but gives incorretc output for gif or animated webp files.

```kotlin
        Magick.initialize().use {
            val wand = MagickWand()
            // getting image
            wand.readImage(src) 

            // resizing image 
            wand.resizeImage(512,512,FilterType.UndefinedFilter)  

            // Saving image
            wand.writeImage(dst)

            promise.resolve("Done at ${dst}")
        }
```

Input: (animated gif having multiple frames)

[image: input cat gif]

Output: I think its single frame and that also messed up but resizes according to input for height width.

[image: output cat gif]

Whats happening here. How to fix it?

Comment: Gif frames are "optimized" to different dimensions to remove redundant data. So when resizing, one really needs to -coalesce them back to full size to fill in the removed data before resizing and then "re-compress" them by -layers optimize. In command line Imagemagick, one would do `convert animation.gif -coalesce -resize WxH -layers optimize resized_animation.gif`

Answer (score 0):

Just want to reference for future, this was already answered in
https://github.com/cherryleafroad/kmagick/issues/3#issuecomment-1068044815

Anyways, to sum up what's going on,
`Gifs are able to save the difference between frames to save space.`

It's due to the way gif images work. Because the cli uses the api in a certain way, and kmagick bindings are only direct bindings to the c api, if you want to achieve the same results that the cli does, you have to use the api in the same way. (kmagick isn't doing anything to the image, it's imagemagick that's doing it; so it's more relevant to check imagemagick api docs / ask them so you can do it in the same way and get the same results).

I'm not sure what imagemagick api they're using off the top of my head however to achieve those results, but I think that doing something like extracting each frame individually then resizing them one by one would solve it.

Comment: Yeah that git issue was created by me there :)

Comment: but not got solution. Dev suggested me to read the api library from which the  kmagick is derived. I tried but it was bit different. I chose another way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I only do the bindings for imagemagick. So if there's any problem with bindings, then it's a bug to fix. But as far as the imagemagick API itself and how it works, that's imagemagick's domain (not mine). The bindings are only a thin wrapper around C, so knowledge of how to use the C API bindings is needed since they're basically the same. So if imagemagick isn't working the way you want, it's imagemagick itself that's doing it (not the bindings). As such, any imagemagick api suggestions will translate almost directly into Kotlin.

Glad you found a way to achieve your goal!